# Search Engine for Network Shares

Tags: network-share, indexing

We have a clustered storage server that contains many project files like Corel, Indesign, Edius, Adobe Premiere, etc.. Also it has lots of image, audio and video files. We are using sharepoint and FAST Search for indexing these network shares. But sharepoint or fast crawls only certain file types. I'm not looking for a search engine that indexes these file types which is impossible. I looking for a search engine that led the users can tag these files. So if someone search a keyword, a file tagged with this keyword can be in the search results.

**In breif, I'm looking for a search engine with these features:**

- Indexing and crawling network shares(especially DFS and SMB).
- Web based search GUI.
- Users can tag the files and also the folders in the network share, and users can search in the tags.
- Security trimming; if someone hasn't permission to read the share, he/she can't see the file/folder in the search result
- Browsing file share in web based file manager for tagging or seeing the preview.
- Image, video preview in the search result; not so important but good to have.
- Farm based architecture(clustered on multiple servers for crawling); not important but good to have.

Sharepoint and fast search server supports these features except tagging and browsing network shares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SearchBlox](http://searchblox.co.uk/).

Or you could always roll your own permuatation using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) and/or other similar tools.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, does this support file tagging? it is important.

Comment: I've installed searchblox and it doesn't work with Active directory I think, and also it doesn't support security trimming. I'm examining constellio and lucidworks right now.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in the question does it actually state it must be free (does it?)

In that case, the suggestion I have is the [Google Search Appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products_gsa.html).  It [seems to support](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products_gsa_technical.html) a whole bunch of windows-type stuff, a massive bunch of filetypes, and sharepoint integration.  It's probably not cheap, but it is supported, and it's Google.  Who knows search better than they do!?

I don't work for Google (although I suspect they'd like that).  I do however believe in commercial support for core applications, and rolling your own will take forever, and be a lot more costly than buying into a solution.  Don't underestimate your time costs in development, planning, implementation, testing.  If you look at your cost to the company of that time, then hopefully (for you), the cost to buy into a commercially supported solution should be far lower.

Comment: Again, I think it doesn't support file tagging.

Comment: I think you should give their sales team a call and ask Them.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint. Simple like that. Really. Does all this out of the box.

http://www.bfcnetworks.com/configure-sharepoint-2010-search-for-crawl-file-servers/

So, sorry - sahrebpoint absolutely brwoses network shares, your assumption it does not is broken.

Comment: Yea, I know that, I'm using it and FAST Search. But you can't tag these crawled contents. It crawls and indexes only certain types. For example it cant index a psd(Photoshop) file. The only thing that you can do is tagging those files like psd, indd. And Sharepoint doesn't support it.

Comment: Wrong again - it can filter psd, you just need to install a filter for it. http://www.ifiltershop.com/ has one for sale. Tagging - you never can have tagging on a crawl if the file system does not support tagging to start with ;)

Comment: Thanks, but as I said before ifilter doesn't support Photoshop, Indesign, Corel, which I'm not looking for indexing their contents.

Comment: And as I said - IPhilter DOES soüppurt it IF YOU ADD A FILTER. I provided a linnk for a shop selling various filters.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to tag your network shares, and you want to use sharepoint too, you have two option. Either you add every file to sharepoint and tag them; or you tag certain files like mp3,jpg,avi in windows explorer, and sharepoint extracts the tag metadata from them. So sharepoint only indexes some certain types' metadata. And some files doesn't have any metadata. so sharepint option is not a good solution for this.